# source devel/setup.bash is still using install space

Tags: ros, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not quite sure what's happening here. From `~/ros_catkin_ws` I do `source devel_isolated/setup.bash`, but when I use things like rosrun or roslaunch, it uses the install space programs at `/opt/ros/indigo`eg.

`roslaunch scannerbot fileWriter.launch` launches it from /opt/ros/indigo/share ... wherever... instead of the devel_isolated space where I clearly want it to launch. This used to work for me (roslaunch would launch things from the devel_isolated space).

Any ideas? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239977/source-devel/setup.bash-is-still-using-install-space/) by [DM2](https://answers.ros.org/users/27473/dm2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-07-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran into this but then tried to reproduce it in a stripped down workspace (only a single package), but then it worked as expected:

```
source /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/opt/ros/jade/share:/opt/ros/jade/stacks
cd ~/catkin_ws
rm -rf build devel install
catkin_make
...

source devel/setup.bash 
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/home/lucasw/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/jade/share:/opt/ros/jade/stacks

catkin_make install
source install/setup.bash 
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/home/lucasw/catkin_ws/install/share:/home/lucasw/catkin_ws/install/stacks:/opt/ros/jade/share:/opt/ros/jade/stacks

source devel/setup.bash 
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/home/lucasw/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/jade/share:/opt/ros/jade/stacks
```

In my larger workspace I've tried repairing ROS_PACKAGE_PATH by hand `export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/lucasw/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/jade/share:/opt/ros/jade/stacks`, but then when I attempt to roslaunch something:

```
multiple files named [bar.launch] in package [foo]:
- /home/lucasw/catkin_ws/install/share/foo/launch/bar.launch
- /home/lucasw/catkin_ws/src/foo/launch/bar.launch
Please specify full path instead
```

Where is it getting that install path from?

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-03-17**:
The install path is coming in through CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH . I'm not sure of all of the details, but catkin sometimes uses the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to find packages, executables and launch files.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-03-17**:
`source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`

`echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`

`/opt/ros/kinetic`   # seems good

`source devel/setup.bash`  # after having run catkin_make install in past

`echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`

`/home/lucasw/catkin_ws/install:/home/lucasw/catkin_ws/devel:/opt/ros/kinetic`

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-03-17**:
If I `rm -rf build devel install` and catkin_make all over then I get a nice prefix path, and I can switch between install and devel fine.  Things go wrong after I make a trivial change to any package CMakeLists.txt, then catkin_make again.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-03-17**:
In kinetic in the above situation running catkin_make after catkin_make install and making a CMakeLists.txt change somehow corrupts includes and the build can fail entirely, requiring a complete `rm -rf build devel install` again.